# Octave cannot plot: cygoctave-1.dll loaded to different address

Tags: cygwin, octave

I am trying to use Octave in Win 7, 64 bit. I installed cygwin64, with octave, gnuplot and x11. However, when I start the X server and opened octave, trying to plot, it came up with this:

```
octave:1> plot(1:10)
      0 [main] octave-3.6.4 5560 child_info_fork::abort: C:\cygwin64\bin\cygoctave-1.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0xF30000) != child(0xE90000)
error: popen2: process creation failed -- Resource temporarily unavailable
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/plot/private/__gnuplot_open_stream__.m at line 30, column 44
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/plot/__gnuplot_drawnow__.m at line 72, column 19
```

Would anyone please help a little bit here?
Thank you!

-Shawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it solved. I got the answer from the cygwin mailing list, as follows:

> The problem is, the hash algorithm used by ld to compute a default DLL
>   load address is not exactly bullet proof, not even with such a big
>   address space we have now available for DLLs.  It still requires to
>   run rebase to be on the safe side.
>
> However, I just found a problem in the 64 distro which results in not
>   running autorebase as part of an update.  This should be fixed soon.
>   For the time being, stop all Cygwin processes, **start a naked dash and
>   run /usr/bin/rebaseall.**

All credit goes to Corinna.

Comment: For info, the mailing list post that Shawn refers to is http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-08/msg00279.html